# boost serialization of struct derived from struct list

Tags: c++, serialization, boost, boost-serialization

I'm not sure how do i serialize a struct which derives from another struct of list type.
Below is sample code of what I'm asking :

//Nodes.hpp

```
#include <boost/serialization/serialization.hpp>
#include <boost/serialization/access.hpp> 
#include <boost/serialization/optional.hpp> 
#include <boost/serialization/list.hpp> 

struct Node
{
      std::string firstname;
      std::string lastname;

   private:
      friend class boost::serialization::access;
      template<class Archive>
      void serialize(Archive &ar, const unsigned int version)
      {
         ar & firstname;
         ar & lastname;
      }

};

struct Nodes : public std::list<Node>
{
      std::string address;
      std::string country;

   private:
      friend class boost::serialization::access;
      template<class Archive>
      void serialize(Archive &ar, const unsigned int version)
      {
         ar & address;
         ar & country;
      }

};

BOOST_CLASS_EXPORT_KEY(Node);
BOOST_CLASS_EXPORT_KEY(Nodes);

BOOST_CLASS_EXPORT_IMPLEMENT(Nodes);         
BOOST_CLASS_IMPLEMENTATION(Nodes,boost::serialization::object_serializable);
BOOST_CLASS_TRACKING(Nodes,boost::serialization::track_never);
```

Please look at the line "public std::list" and let me know if my serialization is correct or not.

Comment: Can you stop posting borked code? And stop using MS-Word for copy/pasting code? It's useless to post code that contains illegal keywords (`Struct`), duplicate and redundant export MACROs (for which the includes are missing _and_ which refer to types in namespaces that don't exist), goes on to define implementations of `Node::~Nodes` (which is it? `Node`? Or `Nodes`?). Etc. It's really quite simple. Just post your working code. If you can't, post a http://www.sscce.org/

Comment: i will do the corrections..

Comment: i have corrected .. where it needs..

Comment: You think so? :) I've edited with the other problems. Note that instead of "doing the corrections" it's usually much easier to avoid "doing the uncorrectios" (i.e. prepare your SSCCE in your favourite IDE, where the compiler will tell you about the things you missed. Quite often, in the process you will have noticed the solution to your problem. See **[Solve your problem by almost asking a question on StackOverflow](http://blog.jerryorr.com/2014/04/solve-your-problem-by-almost-asking.html)**

Comment: do i need to include BOOST_CLASS_EXPORT_IMPLEMENT(Node) also in .cpp file ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know what you wanted to ask. However I do know

1. it's not recommended to inherit from standard containers (they weren't designed for this)
2. *if* you do, you'll still have to specify you want the base class serialized:

   ```
   struct Nodes : public std::list<Node>
   {
       std::string address;
       std::string country;

   private:
       friend class boost::serialization::access;
       template<class Archive>
       void serialize(Archive &ar, const unsigned int version)
       {
           ar & boost::serialization::base_object<std::list<Node> >(*this);
           ar & address;
           ar & country;
       }

   };
   ```

Of course, I'd suggest making the `list` a **member** intead of a **base**. Don't forget to include `boost/serialization/list.hpp`: see it **[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e042244d466840d8)**

```
#include <boost/serialization/serialization.hpp>
#include <boost/archive/text_oarchive.hpp>
#include <boost/serialization/export.hpp>
#include <boost/serialization/access.hpp>
#include <boost/serialization/base_object.hpp> 
#include <boost/serialization/optional.hpp> 
#include <boost/serialization/list.hpp> 
#include <boost/serialization/shared_ptr.hpp>
#include <list>

struct Node
{
    std::string firstname;
    std::string lastname;

    private:
    friend class boost::serialization::access;
    template<class Archive>
        void serialize(Archive &ar, const unsigned int version)
        {
            ar & firstname;
            ar & lastname;
        }

};

struct Nodes : public std::list<Node>
{
    std::string address;
    std::string country;

    private:
    friend class boost::serialization::access;
    template<class Archive>
        void serialize(Archive &ar, const unsigned int version)
        {
            ar & boost::serialization::base_object<std::list<Node> >(*this);
            ar & address;
            ar & country;
        }

};

BOOST_CLASS_EXPORT_KEY(Node);
BOOST_CLASS_EXPORT_KEY(Nodes);

BOOST_CLASS_EXPORT_IMPLEMENT(Nodes);
BOOST_CLASS_IMPLEMENTATION(Nodes    , boost::serialization::object_serializable);
BOOST_CLASS_TRACKING(Nodes          , boost::serialization::track_never);

int main()
{
    boost::archive::text_oarchive oa(std::cout);
        Nodes nodes;
        nodes.address = "Mr.";
        nodes.country = "Puerto Mazarique";
        nodes.insert(nodes.end(), Node{"John", "Doe"});
        nodes.insert(nodes.end(), Node{"Jane", "Greenwalt"});
        nodes.insert(nodes.end(), Node{"Morgan", "Cheese"});
        nodes.insert(nodes.end(), Node{"Walton", "Whiz"});

        oa << nodes;
}
```

Comment: do i need to include BOOST_CLASS_EXPORT_IMPLEMENT(Node) also in .cpp file ?

Comment: @user3382670 I don't think so, as none of your classes appear to be polymorphic.

Comment: originally i posted incorrect namespace and hence was just trying to do correction. I'm really sorry.. if it affects your reputation score.. it was not intensional..

Comment: @user3382670 It doesn't. I was just trying to help you be more effective next time :) (I wouldn't object to you [affecting my reputation score](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) but feel free to find out whether it helped first).